# How does scoping in Matlab work?

Tags: matlab, scope

I just discovered (to my surprise) that calling the following function

```
function foo()
if false
   fprintf = 1;
else
  % do nothing
end
fprintf('test')
```

gives and error `Undefined function or variable "fprintf"`. My conclusion is that the scope of variables is determined before runtime (in my limited understanding how interpretation of computer languages and specifically Matlab works). Can anyone give me some background information on this?

**Edit**

Another interesting thing I forgot to mention above is that

```
function foo()
if false
   fprintf = 1;
else
  % do nothing
end
clear('fprintf')
fprintf('test')
```

produces `Reference to a cleared variable fprintf`.

Comment: when are you calling `fprintf`? Before or after `foo`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MATLAB parses the function before it's ever run. It looks for variable names, for instance, regardless of the branching that activates (or doesn't activate) those variables. That is, scope is not determined at runtime.

ADDENDUM: I wouldn't recommend doing this, but I've seen a lot of people doing things with MATLAB that I wouldn't recommend. But... consider what would happen if someone were to define their own function called "false". The pre-runtime parser couldn't know what would happen if that function were called.

Comment: I was hoping we could get a MathWorks person to weigh in on this. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Initially I thought scoping would be determined at runtime, so it wouldn't matter if false is redefined or not. Anyway, thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the first time the MATLAB JIT compiler parses the m-file, it identifies all variables declared in the function. It doesn't seem to care whether said variable is being declared in unreachable code. So your local `fprintf` variable immediately hides the builtin function `fprintf`. This means that, as far as this function is concerned, *there is no builtin function named `fprintf`*.

Of course, once that happens, every reference within the function to `fprintf` refers to the local variable, and since the variable never actually gets created, attempting to access it results in errors.

Clearing the variable simply clears the local variable, if it exists, it *does not* bring the builtin function back into scope.

To call a builtin function explicitly, you can use the [`builtin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) function.

```
builtin( 'fprintf', 'test' );
```

The line above will always print the text at the MATLAB command line, irrespective of local variables that may shadow the `fprintf` function.

Comment: I didn't know about `builtin`, interesting! Thanks

Comment: You can also bring fprintf back in as a function: `fprintf=str2func('fprintf')` which will overwrite the (nonexistent) variable that MATLAB thought was shadowing it.

Comment: @sebhofer: note that `builtin` only works for compiled Matlab functions, i.e. those that only show you the help and no code when you `edit` them.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting situation. I doubt if there is detailed information available about how the MATLAB interpreter works in regard to this strange case, but there are a couple of things to note in the documentation...

The [function precedence order](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) used by MATLAB places variables first:

> Before assuming that a name matches a function, MATLAB checks for a variable with that name in the current workspace.

Of course, in your example the variable `fprintf` doesn't actually exist in the workspace, since that branch of the conditional statement is never entered. However, the documentation on variable naming says this:

> Avoid creating variables with the same name as a function (such as `i`, `j`, `mode`, `char`, `size`, and `path`). In general, variable names take precedence over function names. If you create a variable that uses the name of a function, you sometimes get unexpected results.

This must be one of those "unexpected results", especially when the variable isn't actually created. The conclusion is that there must be some mechanism in MATLAB that parses a file at runtime to determine what *possible* variables could exist within a given scope, the net result of which is functions can still get shadowed by variables that appear in the *m-file* even if they don't ultimately appear in the *workspace*.

**EDIT:** Even more baffling is that functions like [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) and [`which`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) aren't even aware of the fact that the function appears to be shadowed. Adding these lines before the call to `fprintf`:

```
exist('fprintf')
which('fprintf')
```

Gives this output before the error occurs:

```
ans =
     5
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\iofun\fprintf)
```

Indicating that they still see the built-in `fprintf`.

Comment: I suspected the same. There's actually another interesting thing to observe here. See my edit.

Comment: `exist` and `which` check at runtime, they are not affected by the peculiarities of the JIT.

Comment: How could they? They don't know anything about local variables in their calling workspace. This is even the case in languages like C: if you shadow a global variable locally in a function, then this global variable is of course not shadowed in another function called from there. Not very puzzling if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

These may provide insight:

- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html
- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html

This can give you some info about what is shadowed:

```
which -all
```

(Below was confirmed as a bug)
One gotcha  is that Workspace structs, and classes on the path, have particular scoping and type precedence that (if you are me) may catch you out.

E.g. in 2017b:

```
% In C.m, saved in the current directory
classdef C
 properties (Constant)
   x = 100;
 end
end

% In Command window
C.x = 1;
C.x       % 100
 C.x      % 1 (Note the space)
C.x*C.x   % 1
disp(C.x) % 1
```

Comment: This is truly bizarre. `which C` says C is a variable. `C` says `C = struct with fields: x: 1`. `C.x` gives 100. But not with a space in front of it.

Comment: You might want to submit a bug report to The MathWorks. The variable `C` should shadow the class `C`.

Comment: Nice find. I don't think you need the disclaimer: this is an answer. Well, it's additional info to the question in the title.