# What happens if a function is also a variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, variables, namespaces, keyword

The title may sound strange. So here is the example.

Say `length` is a keyword or internal function that is widely used in MATLAB and someone saved a variable called `length`.

I can run the following script without any issues, but if I place it within a function it produces an error (using R2015b)

**A script that works**

```
clear length;
length = [1 2 4];
la = length;
clear length;
b = length(la);
```

**Function that does not work**

```
function test(a)
    length = [1 2 4];
    save('data.mat','length');
    clear length;
    load('data.mat');
    % load
    la = length;
    clear length;

    b = length(la); 
end
```

> error: Reference to a cleared variable length.

Why does this happen? How does MATLAB treat these situations differently? Should this happen to other functions/keywords?

Comment: Can you add reproducible code (And the actual error).

Comment: What is the actual error and where is it happening? I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: In my Matlab console: 
`Error using length
Not enough input arguments.

Error in loadtracts (line 9)
la = length;
`

Comment: Still can't reproduce. I'm on MATLAB R2015a and here's a snapshot of my console: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AslOZ.png.  Here I create a dummy variable `length`, set it equal to 5, save that variable to a MAT file, clear the workspace, load it in again and try that assignment you're doing above.  It works.

Comment: ```
%% script works
clear length;
length = [1 2 4];
la = length;
clear length;
b = length(la);

%% function not work 
function test(a)
length = [1 2 4];
save('data.mat','length');
clear length;
load('data.mat');
% load
la = length;
clear length;

b = length(la); % error: Reference to a cleared variable length.
```

Comment: Exactly, like your screenshot @rayryeng for script it works! but if rap into a function. NO. That is my question. and since I am not good at edit the comment. Question is updated.

Comment: OK.  That's because of a conflict in namespaces between variables.  To avoid this error, follow Suever's advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The Issue

Based on the description provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13074869/670206), MATLAB actually parses the function and determines the scope of the function *before* it actually executes the function. As such, it wants to know (prior to running a function) whether you intend to use `length` as a function or variable. In your case, it sees that you are using it as a variable, and therefore you *cannot* use it as a function *even if* you clear the variable.

## Demonstrations

1. So actually, if we do the following MATLAB will fail to call our function at all:

   ```
   function test()
       %// Use length the function
       L = length([1,2,3]);

       %// Now use length as a variable
       length = 2;
   end
   ```

   > Error: File: test.m Line: 6 Column: 6
   >   "length" previously appeared to be used as a function or command, conflicting with its use here as the
   >   name of a variable.
   >   A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to initialize the variable, or you have initialized
   >   it implicitly using load or eval.
2. Now, if we change our function so that we first call `length` as a function, then load our file and try to access the *variable* `length` (which was initialized implicitly with `load`)

   ```
   function test()
       %// Use the function length
       L = length([1,2,3]);

       %// Load the variable length
       load('data.mat') 
       la = length;
   end
   ```

   > Error using length
   >   Not enough input arguments.

   Because MATLAB determined the scope of the function beforehand, it only saw the *function* `length` and this prevents `length` from being used as a variable later in the function, even when you attempt to load it from the file.  That way, when you tried to access the *variable* `length` it behaves as if you had called the *function* `length` with no inputs.

   The reason we didn't see the same error from #1 is because MATLAB had no way of knowing that `data.mat` contained a variable named `length` and couldn't alert you of this unexpected behavior.
3. Now as you noticed, using `eval` actually allows you to access the variable. Why this is, I'm not completely sure but it likely that the scope for `eval` is determined when you call it and isn't subject to the scope rules of the parent function.

   It appears that `eval` tries to determine whether to use the function or variable version of `length` at runtime as we can get it to acknowledge both from within the same function.

   ```
   function test()
       %// Use the function length
       L = length([1,2,3]);

       %// Load the variable length
       load('data.mat')

       %// Eval can actually access the VARIABLE length
       eval('la = length;');

       %// Eval can ALSO access the FUNCTION length
       eval('L = length([1,2,3])');
   end
   ```

## Summary

So what this effectively means, is that if you define a variable named `length` in your function, MATLAB will determine that *prior* to running your function, preventing you from ever using `length` as a *function* within that same function. This issue does not appear when working with a script or at the command window because the scope is computed at runtime and `length` can be used as both a variable and function (given that you call `clear length` prior to calling the function `length`).

## The Solution

Best practice is to *always* [specify an output to `load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#outputarg_S). Then the data is loaded in as a `struct` rather than polluting your current workspace with all of the variables stored within the file. Then it doesn't matter *what* the user named a variable, it is guaranteed to not conflict with any of your variables or MATLAB's built-in functions and you can avoid unexpected behavior.

```
data = load('data.mat');
la = data.length;
```

This also ensures that MATLAB is able to properly determine the scope of your function since it can see that you have a variable named `data` and all contents of `data.mat` will be loaded into this variable.

## If you must

If you want to keep things the way that they are but still have access to the built-in `length` function after loading the file (without specifying an output argument). You can use `builtin` to access the *real* `length` function.

```
b = builtin('length', la);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a better **rule of thumb** than avoid the reserved keyword or used function name. If as my edited code above, could you tell me why it works differently inside and outside a function?

Comment: @KangqiaoZhao I have added a much more thorough description that describes the differences that you're seeing including the use of `eval`. Check it out and let me know if it isn't clear.