# error in array of struct matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to train data on various labels using svm and want svm model as array of struct. I am doing like this but getting the error:

> Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.

Please help me out

```
model = repmat(struct(),size);
for i=1:size
     model(i) = svmtrain(train_data,labels(:,i),'Options', options);    
end
```

Comment: What is `size`? Further, `size()` is a function. If you name a variable `size`, then you won't be able to call the `size()` function anymore. Usually, this is a bad idea - I'd consider changing this variable name to something like `sizeOfWhatever`, `whateverSize`, ....

Comment: size is actually a variable which decides the length of array. I renamed this with some other variable but still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A structure array in MATLAB can only contain structures with *identical* fields. By first creating an array of empty structures<sup>1</sup> and then trying to fill it with `SVMStruct` structures, you try to create a mixed array with some empty structures, and some `SVMStruct` structures. This is not possible, thus MATLAB complains about "dissimilar structures" (not-equal structures: empty vs. `SVMStruct`).

To allocate an array of structs, you will have to specify all fields during initialization and fill them all with initial values - which is rather inconvenient in this case. A very simple alternative is to drop this initialization, and run your loop the other way around<sup>2,3</sup>:

```
for ii=sizeOfLabels:-1:1
     model(ii) = svmtrain(train_data,labels(:,ii),'Options', options);    
end
```

That way, for `ii=sizeOfLabels`, e.g. `ii=100`, MATLAB will call `model(100)=...`, while `model` doesn't exist yet. It will then allocate all space needed for 100 `SVMStruct`s and fill the first 99 instances with empty values. That way you pre-allocate the memory, without having to worry about initializing the values.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note: if e.g. `size=5`, calling `repmat(struct(),size)` will create a *5-by-5* matrix of empty structs. To create a *1-by-5* array of structs, call `repmat(struct(),1,size)`.

<sup>2</sup>[Don't use `size` as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288909/what-happens-if-a-function-is-also-a-variable-in-matlab), as this is a function. If you do that, you can't use the `size` function anymore.

<sup>3</sup>[`i` and `j` denote the imaginary unit in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab). Using them as a variable slows the code down and is error-prone. Use e.g. `k`  or `ii`  for loops instead.