# MATLAB: Slow Read-in of constant variables in Script Function

Tags: matlab, performance, function, eval

In the latest MATLAB release, I am using the feature of local functions in the script to simplify and shorten the code.

Right now I have a simple script that does mathematical calculations, up to millions of iterations in a `for` loop. From the loop, I extracted the mathematical part as it is used in multiple independent loops. However, I have the problem with speed and constant variables that need to be in the function. If I write the code without the local function, it is fast, but in the case of using the function, it is 10x slower.

I think it is due to the repetitive read-in of variables in the function. If the read-in happens from a file, it takes forever. The best I have achieved is by using `evalin` function to call in variables from the base workspace. It works, but as I mentioned, it is 10x slower than without a separate local function.

How to overcome this?

The structure looks like this:

```
load('Data.mat'); r=1; %Reads variables L,n

for Lx = L1:Ld:L2
    for x = x1:d:x2
        Yx(r) = myF(x); r=r+1
    end
end

%A few more different loops...

function y = myF(x)
    L = evalin('base','L');
    n = evalin('base','n');
    ...
    a = (x-L)^2; b = sin(a)-n/2; ... y=b*a/L;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to explicitly pass the variables as additional input arguments to `myF` so that you don't have to load them every time. This way you don't have to worry about calling `evalin` or loading them from the file every iteration through the loop.

```
load('Data.mat'); r=1; %Reads variables L,n

for Lx = L1:Ld:L2
    for x = x1:d:x2
        Yx(r) = myF(x, L, n); r=r+1
    end
end

function y = myF(x, L, n)
    a = (x-L)^2; b = sin(a)-n/2;
    y=b*a/L;
end
```

If for some reason you can't modify `myF`, just turn the entire thing into a function and make `myF` a *subfunction* and it will therefore automatically have access to any variable within the parent function. In this case you'll also want to assign the output of `load` to a variable [to prevent strange behavior and not have issues with adding a variable to a static workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288909/what-happens-if-a-function-is-also-a-variable-in-matlab/36289118#36289118)

```
function myfunction()
    data = load('Data.mat');

    L = data.L;
    n = data.n;

    for Lx = L1:Ld:L2
        for x = x1:d:x2
            Yx(r) = myF(x);             
            r=r+1
        end
    end

    function y = myF(x)
        a = (x-L)^2; b = sin(a)-n/2;
        y=b*a/L;
    end
end
```

A third alternative is to take a hard look at `myF` and consider whether you can vectorize the contents so that you don't actually have to continuously call it millions of times.

You could vectorize it by doing something like

```
[Lx, x] = ndgrid(L1:Ld:L2, x1:d:x2);
a = (x - L).^2;
b = sin(a) - (n / 2);
Yx = (b .* a) ./ L;
```

Comment: The first approach works great, forgot about that :D But the second approach looks even better because it is quite lame to parse the same constant variables over and over again to the function. However, with the second approach, I cannot simply load all the variables from the file, I have to specify all of them:
`Error using load`
`Attempt to add "L" to a static workspace.`

Comment: Vectorization is a nice approach too but I cannot implement it in my code, as I need a bit more than just calculations, like finding the right and forecasting a value from the data and some `if` conditions.

Comment: @Klaidonis Right, you really should specify an [output parameter to `load` to prevent strange behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288909/what-happens-if-a-function-is-also-a-variable-in-matlab/36289118#36289118)

Comment: Currently I am using the same first method. I think it still should be possible to improve performance. I tried to place the `load` in `myF` function with `if isempty(L)` to load it just on the first execution and by defining those constant variables as `persistent`. However, the speed dropped more than by 50%. Is it simply contributed to checking that `if` millions of times? And still, the first approach currently is the fastest. With the second approach, I do not like that all variables are shared, if you define a new one you can easily overlook that such a variable already exists.